# Building wheel for python-ldap (setup.py) ... error(fatal error: 'sasl.h' file not found,command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1)

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-ldap

python version is 2.7.18

system version is macOS 10.15.7

pip version is 20.3.4

`pip install`,the error is below:

```py
Building wheels for collected packages: python-ldap, python-openid, pyusb, PyYAML, reportlab, suds-jurko, vatnumber, vobject
  Building wheel for python-ldap (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/chong/pyenv/rh_odoo_10/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-3dY15S/python-ldap/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-3dY15S/python-ldap/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-Zdq9iA
.
.
.
  gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.27 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -I/Users/chong/pyenv/rh_odoo_10/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o
  Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:10: fatal error: 'sasl.h' file not found
  #include <sasl.h>
           ^~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
```

Please help me,thanks everyone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+%27sasl.h%27+file+not+found